# No enclosing instance of type 'Abstraction' is accessible

Tags: java, abstraction

I am getting this No enclosing instance of type 'Abstraction' is accessible problem while trying an abstraction class .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Horse h = new Horse();    //getting problem here`enter code here`
  h.walk();
   
}

abstract class Animal {  
 
abstract void walk();
}


class Horse extends Animal {
    void walk() {
        System.out.println("Walks on 4 legs");
    }
}
```

can anyone please help me to solve this problem

Comment: I think you're missing some code in your post. Is that all in different files or within the same class that contains your main method? I suspect the latter so `Horse` (and `Animal`) are _inner classes_ of your main class which means you need an instance of it to create instances of them. The easiest fix would be to put the keyword `static` in front of `class Animal` and `class Horse`.

Comment: welcome and please check [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Animal` is declared as an *inner* class, which means it must be instantiated using an instance of the enclosing class (which you have not shown).

Change `Animal` and `Horse` to be `static` classes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Horse h = new Horse();
    h.walk();  
}

static abstract class Animal {  
    abstract void walk();
}


static class Horse extends Animal {
    void walk() {
        System.out.println("Walks on 4 legs");
    }
}
```